# Python: combinations for each dictionary in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

Not sure if this is possible or not. Assuming I have a list of dictionaries like follows:

`stocks = [{'name': 'bob', 'avg_returns': '18.345', 'sd_returns': '2.14', 'var_returns': '34.2334'}, {another_dict}, {another_dict}]`

Then I have another list, like so:

```
weights_list = [(0.95, 0.025, 0.025),
               (0.90, 0.05, 0.05),
               (0.85, 0.075, 0.075),
               (0.80, 0.1, 0.1),
               (0.75, 0.125, 0.125),
               (0.70, 0.15, 0.15)]
```

The end result would be to attach a different (whole) dictionary to each sets of lists within weights_list, as demonstrated below:

```
[({'name': 'bob', 'avg_returns': '18.345', 'sd_returns': '2.14', 'var_returns': '34.2334'}, 0.95),({another_dict}, 0.025), ({another_dict}, 0.025)]
```

The reason I was hoping to use it is so that I can call certain dictionary key values to multiply against its respective weight allocated.

The code I have now, all written by @zehnpaard is as follows:

```
def portfolios(stocks, weights_list):
    for x in stocks:
        for stock_triplet in itertools.combinations(x, 3):
            for weights in weights_list:
                unique_weight_orders = set(itertools.permutations(weights))
                for weight_order in unique_weight_orders:
                    yield zip(stock_triplet, weight_order)

for port in portfolios(stocks,weights_list):
    print port
```

However this prints out a combination for every dictionary key, as opposed to the entire dictionary. I tried `for x in len(stocks)`, but it returns an error `'int' object is not iterable` as many of you would probably assume.

Thanks in advance for any help received!

Comment: Step back a moment from how you're trying to implement.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  The nested for loop structure appears inefficient, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem but for future reference, Instead of `for x in len(stocks)` use `for x in range(len(stocks))`

Comment: This looks like a job for [```itertools.combinations()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)!

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed 2 dictionaries within your list like so:

```
stocks = [{'name': 'bob', 'avg_returns': '18.345', 'sd_returns': '2.14', 'var_returns': '34.2334'}, { 'abc': 456 }, { 'abc': 123, 98.6: 37 }]
```

the following code snippet, causes it to print every combination:

```
for weights in weights_list:
    unique_weight_orders = set(itertools.permutations(weights))
    for weight_order in unique_weight_orders:
        yield zip(stock_triplet, weight_order)
```

Current output:

```
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.95)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('var_returns', 0.95), ('name', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('var_returns', 0.9), ('name', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.9)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.85)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('var_returns', 0.85), ('name', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.8)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('var_returns', 0.8), ('name', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.75)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('var_returns', 0.75), ('name', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('var_returns', 0.7), ('name', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.7)]
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.95)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('var_returns', 0.95), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('var_returns', 0.9), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.9)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.85)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('var_returns', 0.85), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.8)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('var_returns', 0.8), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.75)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('var_returns', 0.75), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('var_returns', 0.7), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.7)]
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.95)]
[('sd_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.95), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.9), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.9)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.85)]
[('sd_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.85), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.8)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.8), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.75)]
[('sd_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.75), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.7), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.7)]
[('var_returns', 0.95), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('var_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.95)]
[('var_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.95), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('var_returns', 0.9), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('var_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.9), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('var_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.9)]
[('var_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.85)]
[('var_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.85), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('var_returns', 0.85), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('var_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.8)]
[('var_returns', 0.8), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('var_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.8), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('var_returns', 0.75), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('var_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.75)]
[('var_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.75), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('var_returns', 0.7), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('var_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.7), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('var_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.7)]
```

if you change it to skip permutations, like so:

```
for weights in weights_list:
    yield zip(stock_triplet, weights)
```

It gives output:

```
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('name', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('name', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('name', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('name', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('name', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('name', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('var_returns', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('var_returns', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('var_returns', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('var_returns', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('var_returns', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('var_returns', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('sd_returns', 0.95), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('sd_returns', 0.9), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('sd_returns', 0.85), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('sd_returns', 0.8), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('sd_returns', 0.75), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('sd_returns', 0.7), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
[('var_returns', 0.95), ('name', 0.025), ('avg_returns', 0.025)]
[('var_returns', 0.9), ('name', 0.05), ('avg_returns', 0.05)]
[('var_returns', 0.85), ('name', 0.075), ('avg_returns', 0.075)]
[('var_returns', 0.8), ('name', 0.1), ('avg_returns', 0.1)]
[('var_returns', 0.75), ('name', 0.125), ('avg_returns', 0.125)]
[('var_returns', 0.7), ('name', 0.15), ('avg_returns', 0.15)]
```

Complete code after the change:

```
import itertools

stocks = [{'name': 'bob', 'avg_returns': '18.345', 'sd_returns': '2.14', 'var_returns': '34.2334'}, { 'abc': 456 }, { 'abc': 123, 98.6: 37 }]

weights_list = [(0.95, 0.025, 0.025),
                (0.90, 0.05, 0.05),
                (0.85, 0.075, 0.075),
                (0.80, 0.1, 0.1),
                (0.75, 0.125, 0.125),
                (0.70, 0.15, 0.15)]

def portfolios(stocks, weights_list):
    for x in stocks:
        for stock_triplet in itertools.combinations(x, 3):
            for weights in weights_list:
                yield zip(stock_triplet, weights)

for port in portfolios(stocks,weights_list):
    print port
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would not work. This is actually the same output that I have been getting so far. The real list contains thousands of dictionaries. The desired output would attach one dictionary with one weight, as opposed to each key within the dictionary to one weight. Don't know if that makes any sense.

Comment: `everything should be made as simple as possible but not simpler`, Albert Einstein